# cakephp primay key cant be used for user login

Tags: php, cakephp, primary-key, cakephp-model

Im having a weird issue. My *employee* table has **id**->int(11) as primary key. It also has **code**->varchar(36), **password** and some other fields. This code and password are the two fields employees use to login to the system. I used cakePHP form helper to build the login page with Code field and Password field; and things were going fine.

Today when i tried to update the employee table's another field using $this->Model->save, it inserted a new row instead of updating. Thats when i learned that i need to set code as my primary key. So i put `$primaryKey = 'code'` in my Employee model.

The moment i put that, the Code field in my login page disappeared, leaving only Password field. When I removed the `$primaryKey = 'code'`, the Code field came back.

So it has something to do with setting code as primary key in the Model. Is there any work around this?

I need to be able to update the Employee rows using **code** and retain my Code field in the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `code` is essentially a username field.  If `code` is not defined as the primary key in your database, it is best not to set the `primaryKey` Model property as `code`.

I think most would recommend to use the primary key field `id` to tell Cake which Employee record to update.  But if you must use `code`, try the following:

Assuming your `code` field has a unique constraint in your database or is uniquely validated using Cake validation, you can use `code` to find the record you want to update.  Once you have that record (`$current` in the below case), you can then get the primary key `id`, which is required so `Model::save` knows which record to update.

```
public function edit($code = null) {
    $current = $this->Employee->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Employee.code' => $code
        )
    ));
    $this->Employee->id = $current['Employee']['id'];

    if (!$this->Employee->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid employee'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Employee->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my prob. Out of curiosity, why would cake hide the code field in login page when i set it as primaryKey in model?

Comment: The primary key is what uniquely identifies the record.  For example, it is normally an unsigned `int` in the database.  A user (or an employee in your case) never usually needs to know about this unique identifier.  In Cake, on an update record/edit page for example, the primary key can be submitted in the form along with the user input from the form.  This form data is passed to `Model::save()`, and using the primary key it knows which record to update.  So Cake will automatically hide a field if it is the same as the primary key for that given model.